# How to disable the topbar in mobile?

Tags: mobile

Hello I wonder how can I hide/disable the topbar in mobile (the black one)?
Here is a link to my site: https://www.cyrcl.eu
I'm using wpbakery with Kudos theme.

Comment: Questions about specific themes or plugins are off-topic here, please ask them in the dedicated forums for each product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .qodef-top-bar {
       display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: I have try it, but maybe I don't put it in the correct place, where I have to paste it?